# Computing probability of $k$ errors in a $q$-ary repetition code over a symmetric channel

Tags: probability, coding-theory

I'm reading up on some coding theory and I'm having a hard time understanding error probabilities in $q$-ary repetition codes. Particularly, what I'm lost on conceptually is how to solve problems of the following type:

> A $q$-ary repetition code is transmitted in a symmetric
>   channel, with some probability $p$ that there will be a symbol error.
>   What is the probability that there will be $k < q$ or more errors in
>   transmitting a codeword?

I've seen formulas for specific examples with defined $q$, $k$, and $p$, but can't really wrap my head around the general approach to a problem like this.

Comment: Try looking up the Poisson probability distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution. It might be helpful.

Comment: I would think that with a $q$-ary code instead of a *bit* error probability we would be interested in the *symbol* error probability.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question to reflect that. Been working with bit errors pretty much exclusively up until now.

Comment: @AlexanderElzenaar I have to admit that some of this goes over my head and is probably beyond the scope of the material I've been learning. A good example question that was encountered in the notes I'm reading was: "Let $C$ be a binary repetition code of length 5, transmitted over a symmetric channel, with probability $p$ that there is an error in transmitting a symbol. What is the probability that there are $3$ or more errors in transmitting a codeword of $C$?" I can't figure out the answer (none was provided) and so I'm wondering how to solve this in the more general case.

Comment: Is the constraint really $k<q$? What if the repetition code has length smaller than $q$?